# create .deb package by python setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.4, deb

i want create `.deb` package for my python program. i create `setup.py` and it works well, but when I want to create a debian package using `setup.py` and `stdeb` I get an error.

the commands I use to create .deb:

first:

```
python3.4 setup.py sdist
```

then:

```
python3.4 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

but get error

```
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied;  aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
install_requires=['setproctitle', 'psycopg2', 'psutil']
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/stdeb/command/bdist_deb.py", line 48, in run
util.process_command(syscmd,cwd=target_dirs[0])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/stdeb/util.py", line 183, in process_command
check_call(args, cwd=cwd)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/stdeb/util.py", line 46, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode)
stdeb.util.CalledProcessError: 3
```

I use these options in setup.py:

```
packages=['myapp', 'myapp.models', 'myapp.classes', 'myapp.functions'],
package_data={'': ['myapp.conf']},
data_files=[('/usr/local/bin/', ['myapp/myapp_run.py']),
            ('/usr/local/etc/myapp', ['myapp/myapp.conf'])],
install_requires=['setproctitle', 'psycopg2', 'psutil']
```

and my project directory is like:

```
|  setup.py
|- myapp 
        |  __init__.py
        |- classes
                  | __init.py
                  | ...
        | ...
        | myapp_run.py
        | myapp.conf
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but this might be an alternative way using dh-virtualenv instead of stddeb: http://blog.birving.com/2015/10/creating-debian-application-from-python.html

Answer (score 5):

first try running this:
    `apt-get install python3-stdeb fakeroot python-all`

followed by:

```
python3.4 setup.py sdist
```

reference link: [Use stdeb to make Debian packages for a Python package](http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-debian-packages-w-stdeb.html)

Comment: For me this just made a tar.gz of the source. To make an installable deb package this worked for me: sudo python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb

Answer (score 0):

check out [`debpackager`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=debpackager), its a cli tool for creating deb packages out of any project, including python projects.