# How to setup Ubuntu package (as developer)?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi, apt, construct

I am the developer of Python-Construct module and would like to offer it using apt-get (its already offered on pypi). How can I setup a packaging process?

```
sudo apt-get install python-construct    # to enable
sudo pip install construct               # already enabled
```

Kaitai Struct, which is a friendly competitor, has a package:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/python-kaitaistruct

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283210/7976758

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository